# Carthage - Task failed with exit code 1 when building dependencies

Tags: appium, appium-ios, carthage

Trying to setup the webdriver agent from appium ( https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent.git ). I've:

- Cloned Webdriver agent repo ( https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent.git )
- Opened my terminal
- Navigated inside the Webdriver agent folder
- Executed `./Scripts/bootstrap.sh`  in terminal

Build failed message appears saying "Task failed with exit code 1" . Error message i get in terminal is shown below:

```
Fetching dependencies
*** Checking out YYCache at "1.1.0"
*** Checking out CocoaAsyncSocket at "7.6.4"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/h5/2mqcmnb15y1g476q57tqt8km0000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.a5JJLX.log
*** Downloading CocoaAsyncSocket.framework binary at "Version 7.6.4"
*** Building scheme "YYCache tvOS" in YYCache.xcodeproj
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 1:
    /usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create /Users/cbb01/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A8169g/YYCache/1.1.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/YYCache\ tvOS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/appletvos/YYCache.framework/YYCache /Users/cbb01/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A8169g/YYCache/1.1.0/Build/Products/Release-appletvsimulator/YYCache.framework/YYCache -output /Users/cbb01/workspace/WebDriverAgent/Carthage/Build/tvOS/YYCache.framework/YYCache

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/h5/2mqcmnb15y1g476q57tqt8km0000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.a5JJLX.log
```

I've also tried executing the following but get similar error:

```
carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS
```

What could be causing the issue? Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Read the error, check output in carthage-xcodebuild.a5JJLX.log

Comment: Hello, did you solve this?

Comment: Any idea to fix this issue

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018293/12040041) helped me. May be it could help you too.

Comment: Apologies for the delay @mdkr. /@Alfredo Bazo Lopez. The issue was an Xcode compatibility issue. This issue occurred on Xcode 12 beta v3 but when I switched back to the Xcode v11.6 it worked again. Now that Xcode 12 is fully released it might work now but i haven't checked.