# Carthage build failed Xcode 12 12A7209 building

Tags: ios, react-native, swift5, xcode12

Carthage File contents:

```
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"
```

Error:

```
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 1:
/usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create /Users/samrezikram/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A7209/SwiftyJSON/5.0.0/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SwiftyJSON\ tvOS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/appletvos/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON /Users/samrezikram/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/12.0_12A7209/SwiftyJSON/5.0.0/Build/Products/Release-appletvsimulator/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON -output /Users/samrezikram/Downloads/CarthageApp/Carthage/Build/tvOS/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/px/jx4gljpj47j06qr7blw6b4w80000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.1NVy7o.log
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a Carthage & Xcode 12 issue. Unfortunately at the moment there is no update from the Carthage team to address this issue. However, there is a shell script you can run to unblock you. It has worked for me. You can follow the thread on the Carthage github account.
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-665136323

1. Create a shell script `carthage-build.sh` and place it in your Xcode project

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# carthage.sh
# Usage example: ./carthage-build.sh build --platform iOS

set -euo pipefail

xcconfig=$(mktemp /tmp/static.xcconfig.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f "$xcconfig"' INT TERM HUP EXIT

# For Xcode 12 make sure EXCLUDED_ARCHS is set to arm architectures otherwise
# the build will fail on lipo due to duplicate architectures.
echo 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_simulator__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_x86_64__XCODE_1200 = arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s armv6 armv8' >> $xcconfig
echo 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS = $(inherited) $(EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX)__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_$(NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT)__XCODE_$(XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR))' >> $xcconfig

export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"
carthage "$@"
```

2. Run the script from your terminal to update your Carthage frameworks

```
$ ./carthage-build.sh build --platform iOS
```

Your frameworks should be able to update and compile.

**FYI - I did not write this script, the credit goes to https://github.com/rastersize**

Please follow the thread here for updates on this issue.
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019

Comment: The above no longer work with Xcode 12.0.1. You can get the updated script from https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-699143260

Comment: @Casey you're right, ill update my answer and give credit to the author

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!! It saved a lot of time for me. The only thing which you've missed is that after creating the script you should Make the script executable with this command:  "chmod +x carthage-build.sh".

Answer (score 6):

to avoid `/usr/bin/xcrun lipo -create` issue while updating the Carthage, we have to modify the workspace configuration.

- Open **Terminal** and navigate to workspace directory.

**Xcode 12.0**

- run `curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5/raw/4ba422e5f3a5e7e37cdcb1e232058c5431fc59fc/carthage-xc12.sh -o wcarthage && chmod +x wcarthage`

**Xcode 12.0.1**

- run `curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5/raw/f638b57097897b38fc0b1e62a527a814952968d7/carthage-xc12.sh -o wcarthage && chmod +x wcarthage`

**Xcode 12.2**

use this script in wcarthage file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Carthage wrapper"
echo "Applying Xcode 12 workaround..."
xcconfig="/tmp/xc12-carthage.xcconfig"

# Xcode 12.x
echo 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_simulator__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_x86_64__XCODE_1200 = arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s armv6 armv8' > $xcconfig

# General stuff
echo 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS = $(inherited) $(EXCLUDED_ARCHS__EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX_$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_SUFFIX)__NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT_$(NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT)__XCODE_$(XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR))' >> $xcconfig
echo 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO' >> $xcconfig
echo 'VALID_ARCHS = $(inherited) x86_64' >> $xcconfig
export XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="$xcconfig"
echo "Workaround applied. xcconfig here: $XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE"

carthage $@
```

- After completing wcarthage download, run any one of the following commands based on the requirement.

  `./wcarthage update --platform iOS --cache-builds`
  or
  `./wcarthage bootstrap --platform iOS --cache-builds`

I found this fix at [skymobilebuilds](https://gist.github.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5)

Comment: YES, please find the script changes for Xcode 12.2 in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue - This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile.

It's an issue with Xcode 12. In my case, this worked (fix from skymobilebuilds)

In your terminal use,

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/skymobilebuilds/61f4a95bd62a3db36b52719aeab7e0d5/raw/61affe5b13efaeb83ba3aaf5ef2cb97bab893485/carthage-xc12.sh -o wcarthage && chmod +x wcarthage
```

Then the usage is,

```
./wcarthage update --platform iOS
```