# Carthage update failed with “Alamofire.framework” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file Xcode12GM

Tags: ios, alamofire, carthage, xcode12

i tried to run carthage update Carthage with Xcode 12 12A7209 building, but got following error.(also tried the https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-665136323). Anyone know how to solve it? I have set the build system to legacy build.

Failed to write to /Users/userName/projectName/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire.framework” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/userName/projectName/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/build/ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire%20iOS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework, NSFilePath=/Users/userName/projectName/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/build/ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire iOS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc056c8d290 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Btw, there's no such path ".../ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire%20iOS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/..", how do I correct this path? Thanks so much.

Comment: Hello Michael, please check the following link for related answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984866/7124289

Answer (score 0):

Carthage has [well known issues](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019) with Xcode 12. You should keep using Xcode 11.7 until they release a fix or switch to a different dependency manager.